# viewmodel share data between activity

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm using android viewmodel, but I'm not able to pass and access data of an activity viewmodel from another activity. I can only do that with fragment.

Should I use library like EventBus to share data between few activity?

What is the best pratice?

Comment: too generic as a question to be answered. Which data do you need to pass? If it is about the state, you should keep it in a single place in such a way that you have a single source of truth.

Comment: EventBus does not sound a good idea. It has got its problems even to do the things it is supposed to do, if you start overusing it, it's going to be bad.

Comment: try to google MVI (model view intent) to get some suggestions

Comment: @kingston, yes a single source of truth. what is the best pratice of it. I am currently using MVVM model, but the problem is viewmodel cannot be share between activities.

Comment: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/model-view-intent here a very long blog post about MVI. You can also check https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture where you can find sample apps that use MVI

Comment: You should probably consider adding a data layer if you need to access your data from different parts of your app. Google refer to this as the Repository pattern. It's briefly mentioned here with respect to ViewModel best practises. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54

Comment: @Chris data layer is interesting.