# Master detail flow with shared viewmodel

Tags: android, mvvm, master-detail, androidx

This [android documentation page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) in section "Share data between fragments"  describes how to solve sharing of the selected item in the master detail flow using `ViewModel`. However the solution only works on large devices where you put both fragments in the same `Activity`. On smaller devices the common approach is to have the detail fragment in its own `DetailActivity` and then the two fragments would have different `ViewModel` instances, so the approach would fail.

So my question is how do you generalise this to all device sizes?

I have one idea, I could put the two fragments in the same activity even on small devices. Put this goes against every implementation of the master detail flow that I have ever seen. It would be possible to implement the navigation fitting. And then the `DetailActivity` would only be used for displaying single items as an reaction to Intents. It could instantiate the `SharedViewModel` and set the item passed as `selectedItem`. Then the detail fragment can get an instance of the `SharedViewModel` the same way and doesn't need to differentiate between the two parent Activities.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52315691/3795043) is similar but people in the comments complained it is to broad and unclear

Answer (score 2):

why do you need a `DetailActivity` on smaller devices?
You can still have only one `Activity` holding the shared `ViewModel` between master and detail `Fragment`.

Then use `Fragment` transactions or `NavigationController` to switch between master and detail. The only difference is that both fragments won't be visible at the same time on screen but they will still share the underlying `ViewModel` linked to the parent `Activity`.

Maybe at the time of asking the [sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower) example was not available. Check it since it implements the master/detail flow for a list of plants, which seems to be what you are looking for.